# JavaScript: How stop a function which is started with $(function(){})

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function and then called this function when the page loads, also I need call same the function, but without it existing twice. I want it to just stop from $(function(){}) and call again when an element is clicked on.

```
function myfunction(){
    console.log('message');
}

$(function(){
    myFunction();

    $('#id').click(function(){

     ...some code here ...
     myFunction();

});
})
```

When page is loaded the console gives me: "message" - it's ok, but when click on #id then I get this message twice, if again then 3 times;

---

Here my code

```
function select_cta(){
    $('.cta-id').click(function(){
        console.log('-');
        $('.cta-id').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var cta_arr = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('cta-button-', ''))-1;

        $('.cta-image').fadeOut(300).removeClass('active');
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id').replace('cta-button', 'cta-image')).fadeIn(300).addClass('active');
        if(cta_data[cta_arr]){
            $('.cta-actions #cta_id').val(cta_data[cta_arr].id);    
        }
        else{
            $('.cta-actions #cta_id').val('');
        };

        if(cta_data[cta_arr]){          
            $('.cta-actions #cta_link').val(cta_data[cta_arr].link);
        }
        else{
            $('.cta-actions #cta_link').val('');
        };

    });

}

$(function(){

    select_cta();

    $('.add-new-cta').click(function(){
        var new_tab = parseInt($(this).prev().attr('id').replace('cta-button-',''))+1;
        $(this).before('<div id="cta-button-'+new_tab+'" class="cta-btn cta-id empty" style="display:none;"><span>'+new_tab+'</span><span class="onair">ON</span></div>');
        $('#cta-button-'+new_tab).fadeIn(300);
        $('.cta-images').append('<div id="cta-image-'+new_tab+'" class="cta-image " style="display:none"><img src="/assets/images/page/placeholder_cta.gif"></div>');

        select_cta();   

    })
});
```

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what you're asking. You bind an event to the function, but don't want the function to run when the event occurs?!

Comment: Are you assigning the "click" handler **again** inside the handler? That would explain it, if so ... You didn't post much code however so it's hard to tell.

Comment: `$(function() {...})` is just shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {...})`. Can you post all of your code?

Comment: I don't see why it would do that .. can you post more of `...some code here...`?

Comment: The messages are piling up in your console. Every click adds one message. So, on page load you'll see one message, after you clicked once, you'll see two messages, etc. Clear the console between clicks, and you'll see that a click adds only one message.

Comment: Problem is not with console. This part "$('.add-new-cta').click(function()..." add new div and call selecet_cta() function, and then if i click on .cta-id then console add message twice (or how many times i clicke on .add-new-cta) same time, and show old messagas plius these wich is add after click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that every call to `select_cta` adds another handler to each of the elements. They all would be executed when the `click` event fires. Two solutions:

- Unbind the event handlers from all elements before you re-add them. To do so, begin the function `select_cta` with `$('.cta-id').off("click").on("click", function(){…`
- Better: use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
jQuery(function($){
    function getIdNumber($el) {
        return parseInt($el.prop('id').replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
    }
    var $active = $('.cta-id.active'),
        $activeImg = $('.cta-image.active')

    $(document).on("click", '.cta-id', function(e) {
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $active = $(this).addClass('active');

        var num = getIdNumber($active);

        $activeImg.fadeOut(300).removeClass('active');
        $activeImg = $('#cta-image'+num).fadeIn(300).addClass('active');

        var cta_arr = num - 1;
        if(cta_arr in cta_data) {
            $('#cta_id').val(cta_data[cta_arr].id);    
            $('#cta_link').val(cta_data[cta_arr].link);
        } else {
            $('#cta_id').val('');
            $('#cta_link').val('');
        }
    });

    $('.add-new-cta').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            new_tab = getIdNumber($this.prev())+1,
            new_button = $('<div id="cta-button-'+new_tab+'" class="cta-btn cta-id empty" style="display:none;"><span>'+new_tab+'</span><span class="onair">ON</span></div>');
        $this.before(new_button);
        new_button.fadeIn(300);
        $('.cta-images').append('<div id="cta-image-'+new_tab+'" class="cta-image " style="display:none"><img src="/assets/images/page/placeholder_cta.gif"></div>');
    })
});
```